# How to display different content for different time ranges in PHP?

Tags: php

Trying to write part of a page that would display a streaming player when we are on the air 5a-10a M-F and display something else when we aren't on the air.

Here's what I have right now, but it's not working. I'm pretty new at PHP. Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>streaming</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

//Get the current hour
$current_time = date(G);
//Get the current day
$current_day = date(l);

//Off air
if ($current_day == "Saturday" or $current_day == "Sunday" or ($current_time <= 5 && $current_time >= 10)) {
echo "We’re live Monday – Friday mornings. Check back then.";
}

// Display player
else {
echo "<a href="linktoplayer.html"><img src=http://www.psdgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/play.jpg></a>";
}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I recommend you specify exactly what "it's not working" means. Are you getting an error message? Otherwise community members won't be able to help you, and might vote your question down accordingly.

Comment: you should change your `or`'s to `||`'s   as well, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

1. As has been pointed out, your time logic is off. It should be `$current_time < 5 or $current_time >= 10)`
2. When you give something to the date function, it has to be a string. `date(l)` will throw an error because it's supposed to be `date('l')`.

**EDIT:**

If you really want to benchmark your code, you should use `idate` instead since it returns an integer. Your comparisons would then be as follows:

```
$current_time = idate('H');
$current_day = idate('w');

if ($current_day === 0 || $current_day === 6 || 
    $current_time < 5 || $current_time >= 10) {
    echo "We’re live Monday – Friday mornings. Check back then.";
}
```

Comment: for upvote: you missed one more pretty obvious (efficiency) flaw

Comment: Care to enlighten? I'm still relatively new to php

Comment: comparing strings is less efficient than comparing integers, even with php :)

Answer (score 4):

### #1.

This statement will always be FALSE:

```
($current_time <= 5 && $current_time >= 10)
```

Correct:

```
($current_time < 5 || $current_time >= 10)
```

### #2.

This `$current_time = date(G);` and `$current_day = date(l);` will output NOTICE:

```
Notice:  Use of undefined constant G - assumed 'G' in ...
Notice:  Use of undefined constant l - assumed 'l' in ...
```

Correct:

```
$current_time = date('G');
$current_day = date('l');
```

### #3.

This code `echo "<a href="linktoplayer.html"><img src=http://www.psdgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/play.jpg></a>";` will also output PARSE ERROR:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'linktoplayer' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in ...
```

You must escape `"` with `\` in the string if you wish to output it:

```
echo "<a href=\"linktoplayer.html\"><img src=\"http://www.psdgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/play.jpg\"></a>";
```

or use `'` instead:

```
echo '<a href="linktoplayer.html"><img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/play.jpg"></a>';
```

p.s. `src` attribute of the image must be enclosed with `""`.

Comment: `($current_time <= 5 && $current_time >= 10)` should be `($current_time <= 5 || $current_time >= 10)`

Comment: Note that he said the show starts at 5 AM. By having it <= 5, you're stating that the show starts at 6.

Comment: @Malione Exactly. If it's 5:00 AM, the hour will be 5. This makes it fall to the else condition, which is not desired.

Comment: For a #3, chances are `"linktoplayer.html"` is also causing a parse error.

Comment: encloSed, one letter man! You rather write a comment than click Edit, and fix one char?

Comment: you can't edit for just one letter. you have to change more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the `If` statement Structure so it looks like this

```
IF (on-air) 
THEN DisplayPlayer() 
ELSE echo "message saying Off Air"
```

by doing this you hit the player much faster when someone tries to visit the site while you are online.

this is an optimization that could result in faster load times while you are **on air**.  if you are **off air** it will go through two steps. it just depends where you want the faster load time

this should be used in addition to what @glavić Wrote in his Answer.